# Mi programa no sale del do while

Tags: c++

El programa tiene que preguntar si quieres agregar otro artículo, pero aunque ponga que no, no me regresa al menu inicial y en lugar de eso me vuelve a pedir ingresar otro artículo. No sé porqué el `do while` no jala. Si alguien me puede echar la mano muchas gracias.

**Tengo que hacerlo con este compilador**
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int j;
    int opcion;
    int res;
    char articulo[j][30];
    float precio[j];
   
    do {
    cout<<"\n\nGAMES STORE";
    cout<<"\n\n1. Alta de Articulos";
    cout<<"\n2. Lista de articulos";
    cout<<"\n3. Salir";
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese una opcion: ";
    cin>>opcion;
    
    switch(opcion)
    
   {
    case 1:
         for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
           {  
            cout <<"\n---------------------------------------------";
            cout<<"\n\nIngrese articulo: ";
            cin>>articulo[i];
            cout<<"\nIngrese precio: ";
            cin>>precio[i];
            
            cout <<"\n---------------------------------------------";
            cout<<"\n\nDesea agregar otro articulo?";
            cout<<"\n\n1. Si";
            cout<<"\n2. No";
            cout<<"\n\nIngrese una opcion: ";
            cin>>res;
            if (res==1)
             {
              j=j+1; 
             }
            }
      break;
    
    case 2: 
    cout<<"LISTA DE ARTICULOS VIGENTES "<<endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
            
            cout<<articulo[i]<<endl;
            cout<<precio[i]<<endl;
    }
    break;
    
    case 3:
    cout << "\nGracias por su preferencia, que tenga un lindo dia :D" << endl;
    break;
    
    default: 
            cout<<"Opcion incorrecta";
    break;
     }  
        cout << "\n\n--------------------------------------------- ";
        cout << "\n\nQuieres volver al menu inicial?";
        cout << "\n\n1. Si ";
        cout << "\n2. No ";

        cout << "\n\nIngrese una opcion: ";
        cin >> opcion;
    } while (opcion == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal amigo te comento una solucion que realice algo rápido espero te pueda servir,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int j=0;
    int i=0;
    int opcion=0;
    int res;
    char articulo[100][30];
    float precio[100];

    do {
        cout<<"\n\nGAMES STORE";
        cout<<"\n\n1. Alta de Articulos";
        cout<<"\n2. Lista de articulos";
        cout<<"\n3. Salir";
        cout<<"\n\nIngrese una opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion;
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:{
                if (j==0){
                    j++;
                }else{
                i=i+j;
                j++;
                }
                for (i = 0; i < j; i++){
                    cout <<"\n---------------------------------------------";
                    cout<<"\n\nIngrese articulo: ";
                    cin>>articulo[i];
                    cout<<"\nIngrese precio: ";
                    cin>>precio[i];
                    cout <<"\n---------------------------------------------";
                    cout<<"\n\nDesea agregar otro articulo?";
                    cout<<"\n\n1. Si";
                    cout<<"\n2. No";
                    cout<<"\n\nIngrese una opcion: ";
                    cin>>res;
                    if (res==1){
                        j++;
                    }
                }
              break;
            }
            case 2:{
            cout<<"LISTA DE ARTICULOS VIGENTES "<<endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){

                    cout<<"Articulo:"<<articulo[i]<<endl;
                    cout<<"Precio:"<<precio[i]<<endl;
                    cout<<"==============================="<<endl;
                }
            break;
            }
            case 3:{
                cout << "\nGracias por su preferencia, que tenga un lindo dia :D" << endl;
                break;
            }
            default:{
                    cout<<"Opcion incorrecta";
                break;
            }
        }
        do{
            cout << "\n\n--------------------------------------------- ";
            cout << "\n\nQuieres volver al menu inicial?";
            cout << "\n\n1. Si ";
            cout << "\n2. No ";

            cout << "\n\nIngrese una opcion: ";
            cin >> opcion;
        }while(opcion<1 || opcion>2);
    } while (opcion == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

acá se corrigió el error del menú , así mismo como almacenabas los datos en c++ no puedes hacer un arreglo dinámico a menos que uses punteros por lo cual decidi colocar por default 100 espacios, así mismo cuando indicabas que se almacenara en la posición i al salir de la opción 1 y volver a entrar estaba mal ya que se sobrescribe si colocas nuevamente la posición 0, por lo cual realice una pequeña condicional que valida en que numero estas espero puedas analizarlo y entenderlo , suerte